# ADF Components - Resizing Issues

Tags: resize, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

We have created an application in [ADF] in Oracle JDeveloper 11g Release1.

We are facing a resizing issue.

When we re-size our application.. most of the components are getting cut. They are not resizing as per the screen resolution.

Kindly provide suitable inputs.

it is only working fine on 1364 x 768. :( but on resolutions lesser than these, the components are not flexible as per the screen resolution.

kindly send us a pointer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's little tricky to get the right resize behavior. In ADF every component has two aspects:

1. If it can be resized by it's parent: So if you even put a component which can be resized still you wont be able to if the parent is not resizable for example you should not expect it happening for any child component if the parent is a panelGroupLayout of type vertical
2. If it is resizable: Many components are not resizable at all in adf so no matter how you use them they wont.

Have a look at http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/feature/layoutBasics.jspx;jsessionid=pGxPT2BY4GfrvvWWpTvx3QNTn1F3GTQxFlVwBYSF1WG3wLwBS2vp!-1053881112?_afrLoop=89920899359956&_afrWindowMode=0&Adf-Window-Id=w0

Answer (score -1):

For an Image you can also try using HTML tags in ADF: